# Xamarin - Simulator not updating with replaced images

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have replaced several images but kept **the same image names** in my Xamarin application. Now when I locally debug I do not see the replaced images unless i make a change in XAML then save to trigger 'Hot Reload'.

[image]

Things i've tried:

- Clean > Rebuild > Delete > Debug
- Delete all obj & bin folders in solution
- Delete .vs folder
- Reset Content and Settings on iOS simulator
- Delete & recreate iOS simulator in XCode
- Make missing images 1 pixel smaller
- Delete everything in '~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData'
- iOS simulator > Settings > Developer > Reset local data on next launch
- In terminal > `defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode`
- Download/purchase MacPaw and remove system junk
- Switch Visual Studio update channel to preview & back to stable to induce updating.

The only way I can get replaced images to show up is still making a change to XAML, saving, then Hot Reload shows the images, please advise.

Im aware renaming the images is a quick way out of this but the code is much more optimal if I can keep image names to maintain backwards compatibility.

Comment: Hi ,which version of Xamarin Forms is uesd , and d o you have a check with other version of Xamarin Forms to see whether it works ?

Comment: Xamarin.Forms 4.5.0.539 is being used. Unfortunately switching XF versions did not help with local image caching problem.

Comment: Okey , that's strange . Do you have a try in a physical device to check whether it works?

Comment: Hi, could you share the sample code how to display image in project ? I will check it in local site .

Comment: Did you ever found the solution ? I am facing the exact same problem